# MVC 4 reuse views and view models best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 3 screens that share a section(with model data in it(@Html.TextBoxFor)). What is the best way to implement this screens?

What I tried:

1) Partial view for the common section(_ClientData). 3 views for the different screens. 3 view models that have common property(ClientData), that is the view model of the partial. 
Problem: If I pass the model to the partial as  `@{Html.RenderPartial("_ClientData", Model.ClientData);}` the data from the partial is not submited to the model. 
If I pass the model to the partial as  `@{Html.RenderPartial("_ClientData", Model);}` and reference the properties with a fill name the data is submited, but I can't pass models with different types to the partial view.

2) Use one big View model with all the data required by the 3 screens, one view and show/hide some elements depending on some flag. 
Problem: I can't use ValidationAttributes(for example if one field is required in screen 1, but it's not shown in screen 2 and its value is null, the validation will fire). I can use some manual validation in the controller but the whole thing with the all in one view and viewmodel sounds very bad.

Comment: For #1 (if I'm understanding correctly), have all 3 models implement the same interface so that you *can* pass each of them to the same partial view, e.g. `IHaveClientData`. The view can then expect an instance of `IHaveClientData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partials are usually not the best choice in case you want to place them inside one form and submit together. In such scenario it is better to take advantage of `EditorTemplates` which will solve your problem.

Firstly you would have to drag your partials to the folder `~/Shared/EditorTemplates/` and rename them to match the model name.

Then you can call them in your view like this:

```
Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClientData)
```

Thanks to this your HTML code (the `name` attributes to be precise) will be generated in such a way that your default model binder will be able to bind this part of your view as well.

Comment: Thanks, I will use that.